# convert é to e with php

Tags: php, converters

I know there are a lot of other topics that are equal to this one, but it isn't.

In php there is a function called `iconv`. It can convert `é` to `e` or `ö` to `o`, theoretically.

Here is good example: http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php#105507

Now I'm struggling at the point that I don't get the same result as in the example.

For the English or German language, doesn't matter at this point, I get `Weiss, Goldmann, G"obel, Weiss, G"othe, Goethe und G"otz`. The `ß` letter is correct converted to `ss`, but not the others.

I know the example is 6 years old. But what changed through the time? How do I get it right?

Comment: encoding issue maybe

Comment: well the php file is in utf-8

Comment: Is the server getting back UTF-8?

Comment: server-side encoding issue maybe, then

Comment: I'm using php7.2.5 with xampp, I had never encoding problems. How can I check the encoding of the server?

Comment: in the php.ini is set `default_charset="UTF-8"`

Comment: Better fix your charset issues instead. All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: well the problem is that there is nothing more to change to utf-8. the file is utf-8, I'm printing it in a utf-8 console and php is set to utf-8. that is the whole problem here, I don't know anything more to do

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, just like the comment:

```
<?php
$utf8_sentence = 'Weiß, Goldmann, Göbel, Weiss, Göthe, Goethe und Götz';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $utf8_sentence);
```

[Live demo](https://eval.in/1010156)