# MYSQL 5.6 & 8.0 utf8mb4 : PHP 5.6 utf8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, encode, utf8mb4

I have develop a web site using MySQL 8.0 (uft8mb4) and PHP 5.6 (UTF-8)
Where no issues where raised for the INSERT or SELECT data in the DB.
ex. the word "sévère" would appear as is in both parties.

The problem appeared when I transfered the web site online.
Now using MySQL 5.6 (uft8mb4) and PHP 5.6 (UTF-8)
However in PHP the characters (é,è, ê, exc..) appears not as wanted.

**In DB :** *sévère*

**In PHP :** *s�v�re*

If I *INSERT* the data from PHP to DB

**In DB :** s�v�re

**In PHP :** sévère

I get the opposite.

I assume that it is not caused by **uft8mb4** vs **utf8** since I didn't have the issue before, even though I was using the same configuration.
However, it seems the it is related.

How can I resolve this, so that both PHP display ( *SELECT*) and the DB (*INSERT*) display the same exact information ?

Comment: `utf8mb4` and `utf8` are both UTF-8 and for characters that can be represented as 1-3 bytes will be identical. The `mb4` part accommodates things like emoji, 4-byte characters. If you're seeing errors like this it's because the data isn't actually UTF-8. Check with `SELECT HEX(column_name)` to see what's actually stored in it. Letters like é are normally only two bytes.

Comment: "sévère" should contain the bytes `73c3a976c3a87265` but if you're getting `73e976e87265` then that's being sent in Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: When I INSERT "sévère" from PHP into the DB, In the DB I get the following...

Name : sÃ©vÃ¨re
HEX : 73C383C2A976C383C2A87265

What should I understand ?

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: That's the result of double UTF-8 encoding. It looks like UTF-8 data was mistakenly interpreted as ISO-8859-1 and then re-encoded as UTF-8. The data is bad and needs to be fixed.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Comment: Those accented letters are the same in both utf8 and utf8mb4.

Comment: I modified all my DB with using 'utfmb4'
Every Tables with columns having VARCHAR are set with **CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'**
After that the issue was still not resolved.

In my PHP, before every query I added the code....
**mysqli_query($this->mysqli, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");**

Now it works perfectly.
Thank you all