# how to get rid of unexpected characters

Tags: php, laravel, forms, utf-8, ascii

I have file in which there multiple forms everything and every character is perfect in other forms and fields but there is only one form in which i am having these annoying characters i dont know where is the issue..[image: i have problem in this file]

and if i view page source [image: this is page source view]

how to get rid from these characters your help much needed.

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: The flagged duplicate doesn't necessarily cover all the aspects that could fix this charset issue. Read the two links on my comment above.

Comment: � indicates to our users that we have mishandled their text and lost some of it. Instead of getting rid of these characters, the best thing to do would be to go upstream and handle the text with the correct character encoding.