# Wrong character encoding from form 2-3% of the time

Tags: php, mysql, forms, character-encoding

I have a form in PHP that submits data to MySQL.

Looking at the data in the database, I can see that around 2-3% of the rows contain international characters that are encoded incorrectly, e.g. "Guðrún" displays as "GuÃ°rÃºn".

But, another user might submit the same characters just a few minutes later, and in that case, the characters are encoded correctly

So it seems the encoding is dependent on the computer that is used or some other factor that I am unaware of.

In the head of the HTML, I have this:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

The form has this:

```
<form autocomplete="on" method="post" action="index.php" id="form1" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

The MySQL columns are set to latin1_swedish_ci.

Is there something else I should be doing to make this work for everybody?

**Edit: since it was marked as duplicate**
I can't find an answer to this question anywhere else. I've read through lots of info on character encoding, which led me to having the setup I currently have, but that doesn't explain why 2-3% of the data is behaving differently from the rest.

Comment: Better use UTF8 instead, imo. All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: I had in in UTF-8 before, but I've been trying to change this back and forth because I don't only need to submit it to MySQL but also to a different database through a web service. And I had other problems with the encoding there, couldn't be in UTF-8. This ended up being the best solution, except for the 2-3%

Answer (score 1):

This type of error is called Mojibake.  It's causes are discussed [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

But... You seem to imply that some *rows* have Mojibake, while other *rows* have good accented characters?  If this is the case, then it is a client error -- Some clients are using latin1, some are using utf8.  It is *not* good to mix at this level.

However, if you do mix that way, be sure that each client announces the `CHARACTER SET` appropriate to its bytes.  This is best done via the connection parameters, but can also be done via `SET NAMES ...`.  Here are [*some rambling notes on PHP*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php)

Since `eth` and u-acute do exist in `latin1`, it is possible for the table column and/or the client could be set to either latin1 or utf8mb4, you might consider moving to utf8 for future-proofing the database.

"Changing back and forth" can be dangerous -- especially if you use the 'wrong' `ALTER`.  Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...`.  The hex for `Guðrún`:

```
if latin1:           47 75     F0    72     FA    6E
if utf8/utf8mb4:     47 75    C3B0   72    C3BA   6E
if 'double encoded': 47 75 C383 C2B0 72 C383 C2BA 6E
```