# PHP str_getcsv() does not parse CSV correctly if it contains Japanese character

Tags: php, csv, parsing, cjk, fgetcsv

I am trying to convert an excel file to an array using file() function. Some fields are containing Japanese character. For those field, I am not getting correct data.

Here is my code line

```
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));
```

Comment: You need to specify your charset header, the same as the encoding in that file.

Comment: would you please give an example for me

Comment: You can have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200 if the encoding of your file is UTF-8.

Comment: I am importing csv or excel file from outside how i can add utf-8 to that file. would you please explain that.

here is my code:

$path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        
           $data = array_map('str_getcsv', file($path));

Comment: Why do you think you got the wrong data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only guess without details such like what input Japanese letters were how wrongly converted.

str_getcsv() sees system locale, so setting Japanese locale might fix the issue.

This code

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ja_JP');
$data = array_map('str_getcsv', file('japanese.csv'));
var_dump($data);
```

works with the following CSV file (japanese.csv, saved in UTF-8) on my local.

```
日本語,テスト,ファイル
2行目,CSV形式,エンコードUTF-8
```

The results are

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "日本語"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "テスト"
    [2]=>
    string(12) "ファイル"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "2行目"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "CSV形式"
    [2]=>
    string(20) "エンコードUTF-8"
  }
}
```

As you see, str_getcsv() requires you to know what kind of languages are used in input CSV file. This time you may be sure that the input are always in Japanese, but it is not usable for parsing CSV if its language is unpredictable. Also, you would need to be careful that the directed locale could be missing if your code is used on different environment.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by using

```
mb_convert_encoding($csv_data[$i][2],"UTF-8", "SJIS");
```

This will convert all Shift-JIS encoded characters to UTF-8.