# mysql dont recognize the special charset from query use php

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

i have

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movisat.provincias WHERE descripcion LIKE '%coruña%'";    
$rs = mysql_query($sql, db::getConexion());
        print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));
```

return:

```
Array()
```

and with this it works

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM movisat.provincias WHERE descripcion LIKE '%coru%'";

$rs = mysql_query($sql, db::getConexion());
        print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($rs));
```

return:

[image]

without the character "Ñ" it works

Comment: I guess you aren't in UTF-8

Comment: column collation type is? plz move on to mysqli_* or PDO

Comment: You should use UTF8 throughout your application. I have previously written [**an answer with a checklist**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827) (PHP/MySQL) of what you should set to UTF8. For more in-depth, there's [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/5914775).

Comment: Note that if the character is broken in the table as well, you need to first fix your charset issues, then reinsert the data with the correct charset.

Comment: i used utf8_decode and dont works

Comment: Note that this API was deprecated a really, really long time ago.

Comment: i use mysql api

Comment: i use latin1_swedish_ci collation @devpro

Comment: this is php 5.5 @Strawberry how can does  ?

Comment: i think u need to use `utf8_general_ci` for special characters.

Comment: I will try @devpro

Comment: @WellintongAntonioSotoRamire Read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827 and follow  that list. You need to set UTF8 in the database, columns, connection, HTML header, PHP header, file encoding.

Comment: i get the data from ajax and i serialize the data, is possible that is these the problem? @Qirel

Comment: $paramsUnserialized = @unserialize($searchParams);
if ($paramsUnserialized === false) {
   $paramsUnserialized =  @unserialize(utf8_decode($searchParams)); 
   $paramsUnserialized = array_map('eliminarTildes', $paramsUnserialized ); 
   $paramsUnserialized = array_map('utf8_encode', $paramsUnserialized ); 
}

Comment: No, that's not the problem. You shouldn't use `utf8_encode` or decode, you just just *fix* the charset issue. I don't know what your code looks like in full, so I can't say anything specific.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't specify UTF8 in the mysql connection, in the mysql tables, in PHP, in HTML... Hard to say. See the checklist I linked earlier, and go through it point by point.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify something like this in your connection parameters:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
$con->set_charset("utf8");
```

When writing Data in your table, use utf8_decode. Example:

```
$foo = 'dataÄÜè';
$write = utf8_decode($foo);
```

When you get Data from your Table, use utf8_encode. Example:

```
$result = 'dataÄÜé';
$print_result = utf8_encode($result);
```

Hope this helps.