# $_POST Form advanced security

Tags: php, html

I wanted to ask how can i secure my form from hackers who try to edit the input name? I mean... What i am trying to ask is the following:

```html
<form action="?page=forumpost&action=posttopic">
    <input type="hidden" name="parrentID" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="post_name">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

You see that form? Lets say i open the inspect element option, and i decide to change the

```html
<input name="">
```

When i click the submit button after i edit the input name, i get redirected to the other page `?page=forumpost&action=posttopic` where my form is proceeded. Of course, i get a PHP error "*Undefined index: post_name*". The server is searching for `post_name`, instead of that, a blank name was send to the server which resulted that error. This is the code that throws error.

```
if($_GET['action'] === "posttopic"){
    posttopic($_POST['parrentID'],$_POST['postname']);
}


function posttopic($parrentID,$postname){
    // Form code here
}
```

How can i prevent this from happening? Of course, i am using prepared statements, `htmlspecialchars()`, `stripslashes()`, `strip_tags()`, and additionally checking the min/max length of the input. But that doesn't prevent the user from making my server throw error. I can disable the errors but i don't find that as a good solution. A few security tips about forms will be welcome. Also is there a way for the user to somehow hack my website trough playing with fake forms or something... ?

Comment: You need to add checks server-side if the values are set, use `isset()`.

Comment: Are you blindly using `htmlspecialchars(), stripslashes(), strip_tags()` on all input? Do you know what they do, or where they should be used?

Comment: Of course i do. Strip tags removes the tags, in this case adding htmlspecialchars seems kinda pointless, but i also add that for additional security. And about the striplashes, i think that's also unnecessary but i add it just in case there is a hole that that is reachable by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check that all values are set before processing the data.

```
if (isset($_GET['action'], $_POST['parrentID'], $_POST['postname']) && $_GET['action'] === "posttopic") {
    posttopic($_POST['parrentID'], $_POST['postname']);
}
```

- http://php.net/isset

Also, you mention using `htmlspecialchars()`, `stripslashes()`, `strip_tags()` - are you aware what these functions are doing? You risk mangling the data in ways you didn't intend to.

- `htmlspecialchars()` should only be called on *output* and not input. Storing values in the database with that function will make it a nightmare to search. Store clean text in the database, and instead do `echo htmlspecialchars($myValue);` when printing text around the website.
- `stripslashes()` is not needed if you are using a prepared statement (this function that "could help" if you are not using a prepared statement (alternative, escape the input)). Just keep your prepared statement and ditch this function.
- `strip_tags()` strips HTML tags, which could be useful - depends on your approach, but if you're using `htmlspecialchars()` on your *output* (again, not input!), it's redundant.

Comment: Perfect, just the answer i needed.

Comment: Yeah i am aware of everything that you said, i am coding a simple forum that doesn't have any search bars and anything else. Just posting text. Thanks for telling me about the striplashes, i will remove this code. I thought that i can be vulnerable to XSS somehow trough them.

Comment: If you're using a prepared statement to handle your queries, and use `htmlspecialchars()` on any output that *could* be user-input, you're in the clear. This will also make HTML-input render as text, by replacing `<` with `&gt;`, so you don't have to use `strip_tags()` (unless you have a different reason for removing it, of course). If you're worried about XSS, also make sure your charsets are the same throughout the application (recommend you use UTF8, see [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200).

Comment: I just checked mine. I added to my PDO connection charset=big5;. My database uses that. So, am i fine now?

Comment: The charset throughout your application should be the same, I recommend UTF8. `big5` is not the same as UTF8. It needs to be the same in all your headers, all your MySQL connections, your MySQL tables... Everywhere. :-)