# PHP Select problem with polish characters

Tags: php

I have a problem with searching when I type in Polish characters. When I enter the normal value, the search engine normally works. However, when I enter a value with Polish characters, for example `ł`, I can not find anything.

One more thing, when I replace `$searchingVal` with ordinary text with
 a Polish character in this select then the search engine works
 correctly.

```
$searchingVal = $ _GET ['name'];
"Select * From` customers` WHERE name LIKE '% $ searchingVal%' "
```

Comment: Why do you have a space in the variable name ? `$ searchingVal`

Comment: This is almost certainly some type of _encoding_ problem, either in PHP or on MySQL.  So, you should research encoding.

Comment: But when i put ordinary text with a Polish character in this select then the search engine works correctly.

Comment: PHP and mysql (or whatever DB you are using) can work with UTF-8 and then support polish characters and also search for it. But as stated above, you most likely do not work with utf8 chars, second you have two spaces too much and third, you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: the positioning of spaces in your code is wrong in a number of places. The code won't work at all as it stands.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use that query exactly like that? Please do some research about SQL injection first - or I'll search for your site and use `$searchingVal = "'; DROP TABLE customers; SELECT '";` as an input ;)

Comment: You need to fix your broken charset. Have a look through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very much like an issue with character encoding.  Most likely, your MySQL's charset is set to Latin1 or similar.  Switching everything to UTF8 would eliminate these problems. You can try doing this conversion manually, at the cost of performance of course, so you could compare

```
CONVERT(name USING utf8)
```

with

```
'%' . utf8_encode($searchingVal) . '%';
```

Other than that, your code is wide open to SQL injection, so instead of a SQL similar to your question, you should really use prepared statement, therefore the code might be more like:

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM `customers`
        WHERE CONVERT(name USING utf8) LIKE ?"

$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', '%' . utf8_encode($searchingVal) . '%';
$stmt->execute();
```