# How to configure web pages for accented characters?

Tags: html

I have a simple form to insert products in a mysql table but it's not working with accented words.

For example:
If I post the word "Calcao" it shows up but if I post the correct Portuguese word "Calção", it doesn't show.

Can anyone help me setting the encoding/charsets?

I'm running this on localhost with MAMP and I have tried to set Database charset to `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_swedish_ci` but none seem to work.

I have:

- connection.php that connects to database;
- add.html that shows the form to insert data;
- add.php who takes action and validate data;
- view.php where data will apear.

If I post the word "Calcao" it shows up but if I post the correct Portuguese word "Calção", it doesn't show.

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: I will take a look at those 2 answers. Before I asked I've red a lot of topics but they didn't help me much.
Thanks