# When i have used a &nbsp; in ckeditor and try to fetch the data using php it will give me some weird character �

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

When i  have used  a    in ckeditor  and try to fetch the data using php it will give me some weird character �

Comment: I've previously written an [answer with a checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) of things you will need to consider regarding setting charset to UTF8. There's also [a more in-depth question, UTF-8 All The Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200) - recommend you have a read through those.

Comment: I tried with &nbsp It's working. How you are getting the CKEDITOR data in php?

Comment: i used a only html_enitty_decode function for getting a data. but here &nbsp; is replaced with weird character that is define on question. why &nbsp; is not read by fucntions if there is any way please let me know? many time i face this same problem