# How to fetch site information with php without crashing?

Tags: php

I tried to get the site information **http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15** with the command file_get_contents.
But my output is meaningless?

Output results are as follows

> �\�-]���[sי�{?U�z������A9;Nƻ�W�/{�R)HB$b��e9I�XJ������ŶF��D�����%�yW�8w7A�����ի�z�{>\����N��a]��4��F�ݭ��F�Yߪ^�q���޽\�._����/����\<�����K�q����t�X��3����������ꥰ��ݝN㰷�q��}�n���v������W�^o��������K�vv[V�׭�v�;��+�

Used command:

```
<?php

$data = file_get_contents('http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15');

echo $data;

?>
```

Comment: You need to set your PHP header to utf8. Add `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` right after your `<?php` tag. You may need to set the HTML header as well. See [this checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) I made in the past, and read [UTF-8 All The Way Through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200) for a deeper understanding.

Comment: @catcon Not solved with these methods !!

Comment: @Qirel : I did the above, but it did not work. Can you check this site?

Comment: @Dharman : No duplicate!... Is it possible to use the compression algorithm? for example gzip?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the curl with gzip option:

Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=15');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Shouldn't cURL automatically detect this?

Comment: Thank you ... The problem has been resolved, But only the header is displayed!!!