# html - Datalist displaying arabic text as squares

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, datalist

My offline web application works correctly and displays arabic text without any errors .. except in datalists it displays arabic text as squares
p.s: this problem is only in chrome .. other browser not showing squares
i'm using this codes for utf-8 encoding:

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=Windows-1256\n\n');
```

and for html:`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

Comment: Always use UTF-8. Your header call is ruining the text.

Comment: Make sure DB is UTF-8. IDE opens files as UTF-8. Meta tags (you have ok). Just UTF-8 ALL THE THINGS!

Comment: @delboy1978uk my DB encoding is utf-8 but the problem showing even if datalist options is not from DB

Comment: header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: @delboy1978uk thank you but didn't work..the problem is only with chrome .. other browsers showing correctly

Comment: Leave it as utf-8 anyway, it's the right thing to do

Comment: @delboy1978uk even if i didn't use php to show options

Comment: Where is the Arabic text coming from/defined? DB? Translations files?

Comment: Also look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827

Answer (score 0):

Is a bit late but it may help some one else

for Arabic you should use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">
```

not

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

alongside with

```
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=Windows-1256\n\n');
```

if you are PHP for other language like .NET there is an equivalent way to set the header

anyway  try to use UTF-8 in your new and upcoming project