# Unable to save emoji/emoticon in MySQL from PHP using PDO, but can insert them from cmd/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, emoji, utf8mb4

after some research I converted the field and table collation to `utf8mb4_bin`.

If I paste an emoji in the field directly through phpmyadmin, or if I write the query in the command line, it works fine.

The problem is doing it from the website.

Here is my PDO configuration:

```
$driver_options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => "SET NAMES utf8",
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_FOUND_ROWS      => true
];

$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8mb4;collation=utf8mb4_unicode_ci', $username, $password, $driver_options);
```

Doing it from my website, the emoticons/emojis are saved as `????`.

What else do I need to do to be able to save them correctly?

Thank you

**EDIT**

Solved it. If you use `SET NAMES utf8` in the `options`, it will overwrite the `charset=utf8mb4` in the DSN, so in my case it was ultimately `utf8` and not `utf8mb4`

Comment: Check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/2453432) can give you some ideas.

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Solved and edited my OP, thank you.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yeah, honestly it was there for I don't even know how long. Is it really useless? It was in my case it seems

Comment: See "question mark" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored