# Character encoding issue with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a web application I have been developing locally on my computer, I have recently launched it on my web server with the exact same settings for MySQL, but for some reason I am encountering a character encoding issue where "smart quotes" (’) are being displayed as black triangles with question marks (�), but only on the server.

This is on the HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

My local MySQL database (without character issues) is MySQL 5.7.26 with an InnoDB table with `UTF8MB4` encoding and a table collation of `utf8mb4-unicode-ci`

My server MySQL database (with character issues) is MySQL 5.5.5-10.3.21 with an InnoDB table with `UTF8MB4` encoding and a table collation of `utf8mb4-unicode-ci`

Perhaps there is a PHP setting somewhere I am missing?

Edit:

if I run this script on my computer is works perfectly, but if I run the same script on my server with the same data in the database, it give me the character encoding issue:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include 'dbconfig.php';

$id = 19;

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_TO_STRING);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id=:id");
    $sql->execute(['id' => $id]); 

    var_dump ($sql->fetch());

    while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    echo "Database Error";
}
$conn = null;
```

Comment: All it takes, is one wrong charset setting in your application - *everything* needs to be the same charset! I have previously written [**an answer about UTF-8 encoding**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31899827/4535200) that contains a little checklist, 
that will cover *most* of the charset issues in a PHP/MySQL application. 
There's also a more in-depth topic, [**UTF-8 All the Way Through**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/4535200). Most likely, you'll find a solution in either one or both of these topics.

Comment: If the data is stored incorrectly in the database already - its already broken and its nearly impossible to fix. You need to insert the correct data with proper charset if that's the case, and fix the problems with the insert.

Comment: With  your update: You don't set a charset for your PDO connection. See my first link for a specific example on how to do that (last part of the answer). Nor are there any PHP headers set. Those two are probably your curlpit.

Comment: Was a different version of PHP involved?  (I don't know whether a different default in MySQL or PHP was involved in your particular problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Since this clearly shows a PDO omission, I am reopening)

One-line change:

```
$pdo = new 
    PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;dbname=db;charset=utf8mb4'",
        $username, $password);
```

References:
http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#php
[Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)  (Look especially for "black diamond".)