# Incorrect string value: '\xC1\xA4\xBB\xF3'

Tags: mysql, utf-8, insert, utf

I'm working with a Korean payment gateway and one of the responses from the bank comes back like this:

```
Á¤»ó
```

When trying to insert that value into MySQL database, I get an error:

> Incorrect string value: '\xC1\xA4\xBB\xF3'

I have tried changing the collation in that column to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci` with success.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Encoding and collation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723648/difference-between-encoding-and-collation)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly

Answer (score 0):

Here's my 'top' answer:

If you were expecting to see `정상`, then we need to talk about `euckr`, not `utf8`.

We need to understand where the bytes are coming from, what the `CHARACTER SET` is on the column in the table (`SHOW CREATE TABLE`), the client language (Java/PHP/etc), and perhaps more things.