# Change encoding (collation?) of SQL Server 2008 R2 to UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, sql-server-2008-r2, collation, ucs2

We'd like to move our Confluence system to a SQL Server 2008 R2. Now, since Confluence uses UTF-8 encoding, I'd need a database using the same encoding (I guess that's the collation?).

There's the command

```
alter database confluence set collation COLLATION_NAME
```

Now, as it seems, there is no utf-8, and as I found out SQL Server uses ucs-2 which is basically the same. But I can't figure out what the collation name of ucs-2 would be? Does somebody know about that?

Edit: I do see the difference between encoding and collation now. The Confluence [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Known+Issues+For+SQL+Server%20documentation) suggests that I should create an schema which relies on UCS-2 (because MS SQL has missing support for UTF-8). I have looked trough the Managment Studio and I found an entry for schemas in the **Security** directory of the database. However, I can not figure out how to assign UCS-2 encoding to the schema. What do I have to realize this in the Managment Studio to do so (or which query should I use)?

Comment: Check out [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly) - **encoding** = what characters do you have and how are they represented vs. **collation** = how are characters ordered and sorted. And why any collation selected, you can store Unicode in `nchar() / nvarchar()` columns, while `char() / varchar()` store non-Unicode characters

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7303/multiple-charsets-and-collations-for-a-multinational-database/52948#52948 - Here I explained what I found out about the role of collation in multi-lingual databases and UTF-8 / Unicode support.

Answer (score 4):

According to the confluence documentation you should set the collation to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

We have followed this document and have had a successful confluence deployment on SQL Server 2008 R2:

[Database Setup for SQL Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Database+Setup+for+SQL+Server)