# Does the default character set and collate of MySQL databases affect the stored data in any way?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

I think I understand the difference between character set and collation, explained here: [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly)
**However I do not know if the default character set and collation have any influence on the stored data, after converting a database from Latin1 to UTF-8.**

E. g.: To convert a Latin1 database to UTF-8:

1. Export dump via PhpMyAdmin (or similar software).
2. Open the dump via Notepad++ (or similar software, which allows us to **convert** the content to a different charset) and convert the content to UTF-8.
3. Import the dump again into our database.

**I'm not sure about this:**

- Change the default character set and collation of the database, tables and all columns.

Would it affect the sorting or more important the character set of new inserted data?