# PHP Curly Quote Character Encoding Issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I know there is an age-old issue with character encoding between different characters sets, but I'm stuck on one related to Window's "curly quotes".

We have a client that likes to copy-and-paste data into a text field and then post it out onto our app. That data will often have curly quotes in it. I used to use the following transform them into their normal counterparts:

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string)  { 

$badwordchars=array("\xe2\x80\x98", "\xe2\x80\x99", "\xe2\x80\x9c", "\xe2\x80\x9d", "\xe2\x80\x93", "\xe2\x80\x94", "\xe2\x80\xa6");

$fixedwordchars=array("'", "'", '"', '"', '-', '--', '...');

return str_replace($badwordchars,$fixedwordchars,$string); 

}
```

This worked great for a few months. Then after some changes (we switches servers, made updates to the system, upgraded PHP, etc., etc.) we learned it doesn't work anymore. So, I take a look and I learn that the "curly quotes" are all changing into a different characters. In this case, they're turning into the following:

“ = ¡È

” = ¡É

‘ = ¡Æ

’ = ¡Ç

These characters then show up as the cursed "black diamond-question mark symbols" when saved in the database.  The mySQL database is in latin1_swedish_ci as is the app the messages are received on. So, although I know utf-8 is better, it has to remain in latin1_swedish_ci, or ISO-8859-1, or else we'll have to rebuild everything... and that's out of the question.

My webpage, and form, are both posting in utf-8. If I change it to be in ISO-8859-1, the quotes become question marks instead.

I have tried searching the string for occurrences of "¡È" or "¡É" and replacing them with normal quotes, but I couldn't get that to work. I did it by adding the following to my above function:

```
$string = str_replace("xa1\xc8", '"', $string);
$string = str_replace("xa1\xc9", '"', $string);
$string = str_replace("xa1\xc6", "'", $string);
$string = str_replace("xa1\xc7", "'", $string);
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple hours now and haven't been able to find any real help online. As you can imagine, googleing "¡É" doesn't bring a very specific response.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is that you are accepting UTF-8 input from your user and then inserting it into your database as if it were Latin1 (ISO-8859-1). (Note that `latin1_swedish_ci` is not an *encoding* but a *collation* (for Latin1). See [this SO question on the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly). For the purpose of solving your character *encoding* question, the collation is not important.)

Rather than manually identifying important UTF-8 sequences and replacing them, you should use a robust method for converting your UTF-8 string to Latin1 such as [`iconv`](http://php.net/iconv).

Note that this is a **lossy conversion**: some UTF-8 characters, such as curly quotes, don't exist in Latin1. You can choose to **ignore** those characters (replacing them with the empty string, or ?, or something else), or you can choose to **transliterate** them (replacing them with close equivalents, like `"` for a curly quote... but what do you do if someone puts `金` in your form?

`iconv` will attempt to transliterate where it can:

```
// convert from utf8 to latin1, approximating out of range characters
// by the closest latin1 alternative where possible (//TRANSLIT)
$latinString = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $utf8String);
```

(You can also configure it to ignore all out of range characters — see [`iconv`'s documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) for more info.)

If you don't want to mess around with adding a new library, PHP also comes with the [`utf_decode`](http://php.net/utf8_decode) function:

```
$latinString = utf_decode($utf8String);
```

However, PHP was not really designed with multiple character encodings in mind, so I prefer to stay away from the (sometimes buggy) standard library functions that deal with encoding.

You should also consider reading *[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)*.

Comment: I apologize for the delay in replying. Two days after this I walked out of my job and never had to deal with the company or this problem again. Thank you for your detailed reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use below  code to solve this problem.

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
```

or

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'auto');
```

more information can be found on php documentation website.

Comment: Simplest way to do it, in my case. This answer doesn't provide a link to "more information can be found on php documentation website", so [here it is](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php). To quote: Among the "character encodings ... supported by the `mbstring` module" is "`HTML-ENTITIES` (alias: `HTML`)"