# RMySQL on Linux (but not OSX or Windows) gives garbage data

Tags: mysql, linux, windows, r, rmysql

We have an R program that filters some data in a table and creates a new table with the results. On Windows and OSX, the program runs and our table is created properly. However, on our Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) server, the same R program produces a table with garbage data.

When we compare the garbage data produced on Linux to the proper data, we find that:

- Seemingly arbitrary numbers in columns that should have text values
- Extra rows

We think the issue is something with encoding, but all of our efforts to change the encoding of the database have failed so far.

Our R script uses `RMySQL` to connect with a MySQL Database, filter the contents, and write it to a new table (using the `dbReadTable` and  `dbWriteTable` commands). 
We know that the commands themselves are not the problem, as we are able to examine the data.frame before and after filtering them - the problem is with `dbWriteTable`.

These two links seem to be closest to the solution to our problem, but we have to wait for the pull request to go through:

1. https://github.com/jeffreyhorner/RMySQL/issues/6
2. https://github.com/gagern/RMySQL/commit/b0fbef105ca61d69992a2ec5a5eafde30530b8d5

And these are also relevant:

1. http://zee.balogh.sk/?p=928
2. [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly/)

Comment: without a sample of your data (and possibly the code) is quite difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From past experience I will suggest that this is not a problem in `dbWriteTable`;
and is not even an encoding issue!

It is likely that you have `stringsAsFactors = T` when writing the data.frame, 
and those numbers are the factor numbers.