# MySQL Match() Against() Case-Sensitive

Tags: mysql, match, case-sensitive, against

Currently, my database is charset `Latin1` meaning

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE MATCH(column1) AGAINST('"words here"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

will only return in-sensitive searches. The problem though is that my database will be searched with in-sensitive and case-sensitive searches. Is there a way to solve this so that I can use the same table to do the searches? Is that even possible or will I be forced to make a table with `latin1_bin` charset to query if the user's search is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naïve approach comes to my mind: store your text twice in two distinct columns (with two distinct indexes). The one with `latin1_bin` (for case-sensitive searches), the other with `latin1_*_ci` (for case-insensitive searches).

Side notes:

1. this is a matter of [collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly), not character encoding (a.k.a. charset)
2. using a binary collation (such as `latin1_bin`) has other side effects, such as treating accented characters as different to their non-accented counterpart (e.g. "é" <> "e").