# MySql Database showing ???? for Hindi Fonts

Tags: mysql

I am trying to save Hindi content in db so for that i made changes in table as well with this query

```
ALTER TABLE group_distribution CHARACTER SET UTF8;
```

and when i run this query

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
```

I got below result

```
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

What changes i have to made so my DB support other languages too ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly

Comment: One of the most common issues is failing to set the **connection** encoding in whatever application you are using to interact with MySQL.  Which one is it? (I take for granted that you do have fonts with Hindi chars.)

Comment: I ma using SPring+JSF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue ..Issue is related to table definition see below

```
CREATE TABLE `group_distribution` (
  `gd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gd_tweet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `gd_ht` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_team_lead` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_send_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_added_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `gt_update_dt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_active_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gd_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here you can check it clearly show  gd_tweet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL, have diffrent characterset thats why created issue now i changed it to

```
CREATE TABLE `group_distribution` (
  `gd_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gd_tweet` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `gd_ht` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_team_lead` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_send_to` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_added_dt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `gt_update_dt` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `gt_active_flag` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gd_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: You should include a written explanation as well the code above