# Problems with ÆØÅ (Norwegian letters) when inserting into database (MySQLi)

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8

I'm having problems when inserting Norwegian letters (æøå) into a database. The charset coding of my document (using Notepad++) is set to UTF-8. The variable that is being inserted has the proper characters, but when it is inserted a word that should be shown as "**spørsmål**", is when inserted to the database, shown as "**spÃ¸rsmÃ¥l**".

I'm using the following code to insert:

```
$newContent = htmlspecialchars($_POST['newContent']);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE info SET frontpageText=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $newContent);
$stmt->execute(); 
$stmt->close();
```

And when connecting to the databse, I've tried using

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

I've also done the following:

- The database collation is set to `utf8_danish_ci`
- Using `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` (PHP header)
- Using meta `charset="utf-8"` (in the HTML-head)
- The document itself is encoded in utf-8
- Tried running `SET NAMES utf8;`

The worst part about this, is that I've actually had it working earlier, but I've appearantly broken something (which I don't know what).

Anyone has an idea what could be done to fix this issue?

**EDIT:** Problem has been solved. Apparently the table wasn't properly set to UTF-8. Ran this code in phpMyAdmin

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHARSET = 'utf8';
```

Comment: @chris85 Yes, it is, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: Appearantly it was not, and encoding it to it solved the issue! Thanks.

Comment: I've posted my comments as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character set and the collation have separate encodings (one can be latin1 and the other can be utf8).

> A character set is a set of symbols and encodings. A collation is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set. Let's make the distinction clear with an example of an imaginary character set.

To diagnose the encoding of a table this query can be run, where `##TABLENAME##` should be the actual table name.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE ##TABLENAME##
```

If the encoding is not utf8 it can be altered with

```
alter table table_name charset = 'utf8';
```

Here's a thread on collation vs. character set, [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly).

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all characters to html chars and save into database that way.

```
mb_convert_encoding($string, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');
```

All browsers will display it in the right way.

Comment: It would display correctly in browsers but searching with the db in the future will be a pain.

Comment: you can do the same thing with search term and query afterwards in application. You`re right about pain if you do it outside of the application through database gui. That`s the downside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the default table charset or field charset is set to utf-8.
I know you've said that database charset is set correctly, but tables may interfere with that if they specify a different charset.

Comment: If you run the query given in the comments you will know what it is, @EirikGuldbrandsen.