# How to convert ASCII to UTF-8 in php

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have column name ad_text data type is varchar and collation is utf8_general_ci in my database in which few fields are ASCII and few are UTF-8 which i know by using this function mb_detect_encoding()

[image]

now when i try to display before executing this

```
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
```

ASCII field convert into utf-8 and display correctly but utf-8 field display like this

> (Ø¶Ø±ÙˆØ±Øª  Ù„ÙˆÚˆØ±Ø²Ú©ÙˆÚ‘Ø§ Ú©Ø±Ú©Ù¹ Ø§Ù¹Ú¾Ø§Ù†)

and when i don't execute above code ASCII field display as this

> (??????? ??????? ????????)

and UTF-8 fields display correctly.

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is the collation, right? What is the charset? Arabic won't work as ASCII (unless converted to entities). Was this written as ASCII to start with?

Comment: Sorry right varchar is datatype and utf8_general_ci is collation. Actually when i imported a file of urdu/arabic text since than after fields showing ASCII encoding

Comment: The column has collation and character set, varchar is the datatype. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly Ascii is pretty much the latin alphabet, http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif, so arabic characters aren't gong to display with it unless you convert them to entities. The entity characters are made up of ascii characters/

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: @chris85 - `COLLATE utf8_general_ci` implies `CHARACTER SET utf8` unambiguously.

Comment: @RickJames you can update the collation in phpmyadmin pretty easily without affecting the character set.

Comment: Yes, but a `utf8...` collation _cannot_ apply to `ascii` or `latin1` character set, etc.  Possibly phpmyadmin changes the character set when you change the collation.  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see what you _really_ have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Further analysis implies that **double encoding** is the real problem.  This Answer discusses the cause and cure of such.  The discussion applies to any characters, not just Arabic or the `é` example.  'utf8' and 'utf8mb4' are interchangeable for this discussion.)

Here's what **probably happened**.

- The client had characters encoded as utf8 (good); and
- `SET NAMES latin1` lied by claiming that the client had latin1 encoding; and
- The column in the table declared `CHARACTER SET utf8` (good).

Let's **walk through** what happens to e-acute: `é`.

1. The hex for that, in utf8 is 2 bytes: `C3A9`.
2. `SET NAMES latin1` saw it as 2 latin1-encoded *characters* `Ã` and `©` (hex: `C3` and `A9`)
3. Since the target was `CHARACTER SET utf8`, those 2 characters needed to be converted.
   `Ã` was converted to utf8 (hex `C383`) and `©` (hex `C2A9`)
4. So, 4 bytes were stored (hex `C383 C2A9` for `ÃƒÂ©`)

When reading it back out, the reverse steps were performed,
and the end user possibly noticed nothing wrong.  What is wrong:

- The data stored is 2 times as big as it should be (3x for Asian languages).
- Comparisions for equal, greater than, etc may not work as expected.
- `ORDER BY` may not work as expected.

**The fix** (2 parts):

1. Be sure to do `SET NAMES utf8;` (or equivalent, such as `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')`).  Keep in mind that `init_connect` is not executed when you connect as `root`.
2. Something like this will repair your data:

   `UPDATE tbl SET col = CONVERT(BINARY(
                          CONVERT(col USING latin1))
                        USING utf8);`

Answer (score 0):

you can use after retrieving data:

```
//string mb_convert_encoding ( string $str , string $to_encoding [, mixed $from_encoding = mb_internal_encoding() ] )

$str = mb_convert_encoding($row['ad_text'], 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
```

or

```
$str = mb_convert_encoding($row['ad_text'], 'UTF-8', 'auto');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

here is SUPPORTED encoding http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.supported-encodings.php

Comment: $str = mb_convert_encoding($row['ad_text'], "utf8");
print mb_detect_encoding($str); Still $str is ascii

Comment: $str = mb_convert_encoding($row['ad_text'],  'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
echo $str;

Comment: Do not use any conversion functions, that only adds to the mess.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
iconv('ASCII', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', $str);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: try this one `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text)` or `iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text)`

Comment: Do not use any conversion functions, that only adds to the mess.

Answer (score 0):

`Ø¶Ø±ÙˆØ±Øª Ù„ÙˆÚˆ` is "Mojibake" for 'ضرورت لوڈ'.  It comes from one form of mistake.

`??????` comes from a different mistake.

- I assume the bytes in your client are utf8-encoded.  (Good)
- You connected with `SET NAMES latin1` (or `set_charset('latin1')` or ...), probably by default.  (It should have been `utf8`.)
- The column(s) in the table(s) were probably `CHARACTER SET latin1`.  (It should have been utf8.)
- The HTML output should include `<meta charset=UTF-8>`.

Let's check one more thing...  Please do `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE...` to pick up that string (or something like it).  You *should* see

```
D8B6 D8B1 D988 D8B1 D8AA D984 D988 DA88
```

(without the spaces) for the HEX for 'ضرورت لوڈ'.  If you do, then it was correctly stored.  If you get this, you have the dreaded "double encoding":

```
C398 C2B6 C398 C2B1 C399 CB86 C398 C2B1 C398 C2AA C399 E2809E C399 CB86 C39A CB86
```

Back to the title... "ASCII", at least the 7-bit stuff that includes digits and English letters, is a *subset* of utf8.  So, there is never a need to "convert ascii to utf8".

Bottom line:

- Don't use mysql_* API; switch to mysqli_* or PDO.
- Establish utf8 on the connection: `mysqli_set_charset('utf8')` or equivalent.
- Make sure the column/table is `CHARACTER SET utf8`.  (See note below.)
- Check the html for the meta tag.

Note:  If the `CHARACTER SET` is not utf8, I need to know what the HEX is before advising you on how to `ALTER` the table without screwing things up further.

Comment: If i do mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $con) and than mysql_client_encoding($con) whats the output should be??

Comment: How do i stop double encoding for this C398 C2B6 C398 C2B1 C399 CB86 C398 C2B1 C398 C2AA C399 E2809E C399 CB86 C39A CB86

Comment: Do _not_ mix `mysql_*` functions and `mysqli_*` functions.  Use only `mysqli_*`.