# SQL : error with an inner join, probably sthg simple

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables with the same columns (id, country_code), example :

```
Table A
--------
id   country_code
1    fr
2    fr
3    fr

Table B
--------
id   country_code
1    ua
2    fr
3    uk
```

I would like to get all fields in B where the country_code is different of the one in A for each same id,

Example expected :

```
id  country_code
1   ua
3   uk
```

I tried with inner join but without any success, any idea?

Here is the error I get :

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'
```

But in Workbench those fields and tables havee the same collation (set as "Table default"), it's strange..

Answer : I've checked all colations by doing

```
show table status;
```

and I updated the Collation column, now it works okay.

Comment: Show us the inner join(s) you tried!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use Collate keyword to change collation:

```
select b.id,b.country_code
from b join a
on b.id = a.id and b.country_code <> a.country_code collate utf8_unicode_ci;
```

For more information about collation: [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly)

Comment: it works but why it doesn't work without this collate added in the query?

Comment: Because you two different collations in table a and table b, in other terms it's like b.country_code and a.country_code are in different languages, so you need to translate one of them to the other one's language. To better understand this check the link in my answer.

Comment: but in Workbench each fields and also table use the same collation (Collation= "Table default"), it's strange..

Comment: well you need to specify collation instead of using default values (Table default is not a collation), default values can be different between tables.

Comment: you were right, I checked all collations with show table status; and I saw different collations, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `join`:

```
select b.*
from b join
     a
     on b.id = a.id and b.country_code <> a.country_code;
```

Comment: thank you but I get : "Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'", any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.id,b.country_code
from b 
left join a on b.country_code = a.country_code
where a.country_code is null
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.