# how should i insert text in mysql database using php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How should i insert texts messages in mysql database using PHP.

My Code:

```
<?php

$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
$message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $message);

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO messages (messages) VALUE ('$message')");
?>
```

My problem :

When i am entering this sign (°) in message text area, it inserts nothing.

Comment: What is `var_dump($_POST['message])` giving you? Your column is named "massages" in plural?

Comment: Also publish `var_dump($message)` after modifications has been done. Give us the raw input in `textarea` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer prepared statements over escaping string.

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');

if (!($stmt = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO `messages` (`messages`) VALUES(?);')))
{
  echo "error {$connection->errno} on prepare: {$mysqli->error}";
}


if (!$stmt->bind_param('s', $message))
{
  echo "error {$stmt->errno} on bind param: {$stmt->error}";
}

if (!$stmt->execute())
{
  echo "error {$stmt->errno} on execute: {$stmt->error}";
}
```

Comment: Don't you think that this code is a bit bloated? What you say if I show you the way to have error messages without adding three lines of code to the every mysqli statement?

Comment: @YourCommonSense - Introducing the PO into PDO exceptions would be overkill. That's what I'm doing in my own code or recommend advanced coders. Answers should be somehow on the level of the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

Try to quote the value like that:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO messages (messages) VALUE ('$message')");
```

Comment: this is only the example, and thats not the problem, i am using quotes, i updated the code also.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code before you execute your query

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```

and set collation of your column to

```
utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: what that means, are you sure it will not harm any data in database ?

Comment: It will allow to store special characters to your column. UTF-8 is the dominant character encoding(You can search more about that) and it will not harm any data but for safest way you can take backup of your database before testing anything with it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly this may help you..

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi - The command sets explicitly the character set of the *connection*. This affects only the SQL communication, not how the data is stored into the table. The charset of the PHP mysql driver will be set as well as on the mysql server.

Comment: brother can you show me any example of how should i put mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8"); before my query. And if i change the collation of my column to utf8_general_ci then will i have to change all the queries or anything, will i have to change the varchar limit or length ? Please tell me bro.

Comment: @ShubhamTripathi - When explicitly setting the connection encoding, you usually do that immediately after establishing the connection.

Answer (score -1):

Use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) and [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php)

Here is some example.

```
$str = '° some special chars ';

$str_encoded = base64_encode($str);
echo $str_encoded; //ready to be inserted to the DB
$str_decoded = base64_decode($str_encoded);
echo  $str_decoded; // retrieved and decoded
```