# Moodle MySQL to MSSQL migration

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, encoding, moodle

We have `Moodle 3.0` and are trying to migrate it from `MySQL` to `MSSQL`. All went well until we saw the major problem with the special characters.

In the new database we have the characters shown, i.e `Fußball`is found like that inside the database:

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | category | sortorder | fullname |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  2 |        2 |     20002 | Fußbal   |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

But in Moodle all fields, when we open the settings of them, where we have the names of blocks, courses, users, etc. are `emty`, as if there is no data inside. On the other side we have them shown in Moodle - but for example the course named `Fußbal` is shown as `Fu?ball`

The collation we are using for the `MySQL` is `utf8_general_ci` is and for `MSSQL` `SQL_Latin1_Genaral_CP1_CS_AS`.

Comment: You should check and match character sets first. Collation doesn't determine the characters encoding, character set does. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341273/what-does-character-set-and-collation-mean-exactly

Comment: Our presumption is, that the characters work fine and Moodle could not read them from the new database

Comment: Why are you trying to put Unicode characters in a Latin database? Of course this won't work.

Comment: Western European characters (including `ß`) are handled by latin1, so I am surprised that you had trouble.  However, you needed to inform the sender and/or receiver what character set was being transmitted.  _That_ is probably where the problem lies.