# Convert latin1_swedish_ci string to utf8_persian_ci

Tags: php, utf-8

My String is `Ù‚Ø³Ù…Øª 10 Ù¾Ø§ÛŒØ§Ù† Ø³Ø±ÛŒØ§Ù„`

I want convert to `utf-8`

I use iconv, utf_decode and ... but not work for me

note: I do not want use charset for mysql

Comment: Collation is not the same as charset. You need to set the charset in mysql too. Data which has incorrect encoding will not be magically fixed by fixing the charset, the data needs to be updated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897407/mysql-and-php-utf-8-with-cyrillic-characters/31899827#31899827

Comment: See also [What does character set and collation mean exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/341273)